# Firebase Firestore Query using react-redux-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, react-redux-firebase

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match/projects/{project} {
      allow read: if 
       get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(project)).data.uid == 
       request.auth.uid;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

here i am doing the queries :

```
firestoreConnect((props) => { 
  return ([{ collection: 'projects', where: [["uid", "==", props.auth.uid]] }]) 
})
```

But I am getting an error :

> Error with profile listener: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>   Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>       at new FirestoreError (index.cjs.js:402).

when i check using simulator entering document id in path i get read access.
I am not getting where i am wrong. Maybe in the queries.

When I change the rules to:

```
allow read : if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```

there is no error, and data is displayed.

Why its happening is it bug or i am doing something wrong? I know firebase rules are not filters.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the documents separately (and unnecessarily), and I don't think the rules engine is able to evaluate and validate that the query will never return disallowed documents against this condition.

Try this:

```
allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```